# Linksys WMP54G setup file crashes?

Tags: drivers

I am reformatting and putting a fresh installation of windows on 3 machines for a daycare.  They each happen to have a PCI wifi adapter.  There is not a driver for this from the desktop's manufactuer.  So I took it out to see if it had a brand name on it.

It is a linksys wireless-g PCI adapter.  It does not have a version on it so I assume it is 1.0.  I download the driver package from linksys website.  Unzip the setup files.  Run setup.  It goes through one loading bar, then flashes a purple(the linksys setup) rectangularish shape for about one sec and then crashes.

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit:  I am running windows xp professional.

Comment: What make/model computer is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try different versions (especially the most recent)
- Make sure you're downloading for the proper OS
- Delete any existing drivers
- Try generic drivers from Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Scrap the useless Linksys software. Also check multiple Linksys sites (they have different versions of drivers on support pages from different regions.

Find a desktop you can install the Linksys package. It should create a directory under C:\Program Files\Linksys.

Go in there and grab the INF driver files for you WMP54G. Copy it to a thumbdrive and archive a copy somewhere.

Do the normal hardware installation using these INF files - the Linksys wireless utility really blows.

There are 4 **hardware** revisions of the WMP54G - make sure you choose the right driver!